# Qt C++ - QListWidget layout doesn't scale to fit the content

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have a `QWidget rzadKontener` that represents a row in a `QListWidget`.

```
QWidget* rzadKontener = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout* rzadKontenerLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
rzadKontenerLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
rzadKontenerLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
rzadKontener->setObjectName("rzadKontener_" + poziom);
rzadKontener->setFixedHeight(200);
rzadKontener->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
rzadKontener->setLayout(rzadKontenerLayout);

 (....)

QListWidgetItem* newItemRzad = new QListWidgetItem;
newItemRzad->setSizeHint(QSize(listSize*225, 200));
QString poziomText = poziom;
newItemRzad->setText(poziomText);
newItemRzad->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::white));

ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->addItem(newItemRzad);
ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->setItemWidget(newItemRzad, rzadKontener);
```

It contains a number of items, that are `QWidgets` with pictures, buttons and text. It is then placed in a `QListWidget` as a row full of these items. When I add 5 items at once, while creating a new `rzadKontener`, scroll bars in the `QListWidget` will appear. But if I add 3 and then 2 items later on, they'll go out of bounds without a scrollbar. How can I force the layout to scale to the new `rzadKontener`'s size?

Comment: It is simple: you have only created the layout in some container widget. But you want the content of layout to be scaled, right? rzadKontener->addWidget(pSomeOtheWidget); I guess.

Comment: @AlexanderVX `rzadKontenerLayout->addWidget(...)` i guess

Comment: @AlexanderVX I am doing that. `ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->findChild<QWidget*>(objectName)->layout()->addWidget(zdjecieKontener);` where `objectName` equals `"rzadKontener_" + poziom` . `zdjecieKontener` is a picture, a name, a lineEdit and a button. It adds it, but doesn't scale.

Comment: Yes, I meant rzadKontenerLayout->addWidget(...)  thank you.

Comment: @Petersaber make sure that     widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

Comment: @AlexanderVX it's set. But maybe I have to edit the `QListWidgetItem` instead? But how do I access that...

Comment: The policy should be set for the widget you are inserting to layout. And I am unsure why that fixed length at container?

Comment: @AlexanderVX it'd be easiest to just adjust the QListWidgetItem size, but I have no idea how

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. Instead of modifying the QWidget inside the list, I should be modifying the `QListWidgetItem` it's inside of (the parent...).

```
QWidget* newPicture = new QWidget;
yadda yadda yadda (....)
int currentRowWidth = ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->findChild<QWidget*>(objectName)->width(); //gets max width of rzadKontener, which fills the entirety of the row - it equals the QListWidgetItem's width
int newWidth = currentRowWidth + 225; //225 is a fixed width of newPicture 
ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->item(0)->setSizeHint(QSize(newWidth, 200));

ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->findChild<QWidget*>(objectName)->layout()->addWidget(newPicture );
```

We can do `ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->item(0)->setSizeHint(QSize(newWidth, 200));` instead of a specific row (`->item(row)`), because the list is a rectangle. Doesn't matter which row we enlarge, the entire thing will stretch anyway.

But, if you want to get the row number, you can do it this way:

```
int row=0; 
//we make a list. Each of my QListWidgetItem has a unique string poziom in it, so I can filter by that. 
QList<QListWidgetItem *> items = ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->findItems(poziom, Qt::MatchContains);
if (items.size() > 0) {
    //we use the first (and only, in my case) item on this list to get row number
    row = ui->listWidgetZdjeciaModelu->row(items[0]); 
}
```

Weird thing is, I already tried this. Must've kept making a typo.